# docker compose set volume owner

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a container for php development. By default the UID and GID in the container is 1000 which is different to my users host uid and gid. Once the container has created files in the volume I can chmod them, which gives me access, but when new files are created i.e. by php artisan, I have to keep running chmod again.

How do I change the uid and gid of the files that are created in the volume?

I have tried to set the user to my uid and gid i.e. user: xxxxx:xxxx but that results in permission errors in the container. It manages to  create the my-project folder, but sets the owner as root.

```
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/tests/Unit': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/tests/CreatesApplication.php': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/tests/Feature': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/tests': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/.buildcomplete': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/public/favicon.ico': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/public/index.php': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/public/robots.txt': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/public/.htaccess': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/public': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/.gitignore': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app/.env.example': Operation not permitted
docker-test-myapp-1    | chown: changing ownership of '/app': Operation not permitted
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```yaml
# Copyright VMware, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0

version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:11.1
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_myapp
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_myapp
  myapp:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=bn_myapp
      - DB_DATABASE=bitnami_myapp
    volumes:
      - './my-project:/app'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```